# getActionView() of my MenuItem return null

Tags: android, view, null, android-actionbar

I just would like to tweak the View of an ActionBar MenuItem by code.

Unfortunately, it seems that  getActionView always return null!

My code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = this.getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.folder, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    MenuItem menuFolder = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_folder);
    Log.i("", "* onPrepareOptionsMenu *" + menuFolder);
    Log.i("", "* getActionView *" + menuFolder.getActionView());
```

Log is:

> 01-11 22:13:42.884: I/(7893): * onPrepareOptionsMenu
>   *com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuItemWrapper@41401ac8
>
> 01-11 22:13:42.884: I/(7893): * getActionView *null

Thank a lot for any help

Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item 
          android:id="@+id/menu_folder"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_archive"
          android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Please show `R.menu.folder`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`getActionView()` only works if there's a custom actionView from `setActionView`.

Comment: Is there an alternative to access the view of the MenuItem?

Comment: Depends.  Do you want to tweak just this button, or all buttons?  If it's just this button, you should probably set a custom view.  If its all buttons, you should probably use styles if at all possible.  What changes are you trying to make?

Comment: I want to put a "badge" on an icon when there are new content in the application, so I need the View to add this little counter

Comment: Ok, then you want to create a view for the item and use setActionView to set it.  That's the right answer.  There may be a hack to do it by getting the action bar and traversing its children looking for the view, but you don't want to do that.

Comment: There is one moment. I have project with ActionBarSherlock and two menu folders: just menu and menu-v11. In menu-v11 I have menu item with `android:actionLayout="@layout/search_layout"` and it works on all Android 11+ versions. After this I copied this project and use appcompat-v7 instead of ActionBarSherlock (minApiVersion now is 11). And I have two menu folders: menu and menu-v14. Now `getActionView()` returns null! A had to write `menuSearch.setActionView(R.layout.search_layout);`!  

So check it - in ActionBarSherlock it should works from xml

Comment: I have the same problem with AppCompat. I do as @rocknow suggested, `menuSearch.setActionView(R.layout.search)` and it works.

Comment: I had the same issue and I my error was that I wasn't properly using the actionLayout xml attribute properly. First of all, you must define a custom namespace in the menu tag like this 
`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
Then on the menu item you want to have to use the actionLayout attribute like this:
`app:actionLayout="@layout/month_picker"` 
In this case the month_picker layout is a spinner. Doing this makes it unnecessary to use the setActionView method.

Answer (score 88):

you should use

```
app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_actionbar_basket"
```

thats the trick
if you use

```
android:actionLayout="@layout/menu_actionbar_basket"
```

you would always get null exception in default toolbar.

Answer (score 34):

For me the solution that worked is to use **app** namespace instead of android.

`app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"`

Don't forget to declare it:
`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: You can also use the actionLayout attribute to set custom Layouts. In my case I was using a Spinner which I had defined in its own xml.

Answer (score 8):

****First Solution****

This happen may be you not set **actionLayout** in Menu file
so set your **actionLayout** in menu file

`app:actionLayout="@layout/your_action_layout"`

****Second Solution****
and the second solution is

****from****

`android:actionLayout="@layout/your_action_layout"`

**to**

`app:actionLayout="@layout/your_action_layout"`

Answer (score 6):

If your debug build is working without any issues and issue is only with release build then this may be because of proguard configuration. If you have enabled proguard in your application then add below line to proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to get the MenuItem View i use:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.someMenuItem:

            View v = findViewById(R.id.someMenuItem);
            doSomethingWithView(v);

            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: this is the closest to my needs but getItemId() returns zero