# getSearchableInfo returns NULL

Tags: android, android-searchmanager

After trying ALL of the solutions in stackoverflow about this problem, I decided to ask it here.

I'm trying to implement search bar in my Action bar.
I'm using **AppCompatActivity** and imported **android.support.v7.widget.SearchView**.

For the record, I'm using PageManager and TabLayout if it has any releation.

I get java.lang.NullPointerException error in the following line:

```
searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

This is my code:

search bar declration at **menu_main.xml:**

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/searchPlace"
        android:title="@string/search_hint"
        android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

**searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".searchResultActivity" />

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".searchResultActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

            <!-- to identify this activity as "searchable" -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
```

Search code in my **MainActivity.java onCreateOptionsMenu:**

```
// Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.searchPlace).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

Logcat error:

```
Process: il.co.test.test, PID: 1642
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at il.co.test.test.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:106)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2538)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:262)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:267)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:448)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure, and I don't know how to check it - but I am pretty sure my **getActionVIew()** returns **NULL**.

UPDATE 2 - FIXED!

After checking some stackoverflow's about getActionView() null problem,
The 2nd answer at [getActionView() of my MenuItem return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286768/getactionview-of-my-menuitem-return-null) fixed my problem.
I had to use namespace **app** instaed of **android**.

Really painful!

Hope someone can find my mistake and help me fix it, since I tried many solutions for 6 hours.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly cause nullPointerException - search manager? Did you define it? Post stacktrace.

Comment: If you break on the line where you `setSearchableInfo` and use the evaluate expression tool to run `getComponentName()`, what is the result?

Comment: what do you need `SearchableInfo` for?

Comment: @kolombo I added the full logcat

Comment: @nukeforum Sry I didn't understand what you mean to do

Comment: @pskink to show search in the action bar...

Comment: @TheUnreal I'm trying to guide you to checking the return value on `getComponentName()`. Have you checked at run time that it is in fact returning valid data for the `getSearchable()` method?

Comment: you don't need it at all,  just use `menu.findItem(R.id.searchPlace).getActionView();`

Comment: @pskink What did you mean by sating IT at "you dont need IT"?

Comment: @nukeforum getComponentName() does not return null

Comment: just see @kolombo answer: `"you dont need searchable configuration, dont need strokes in manifest, dont need SearchManager and other stuff. Just declare search item in the menu and thats it."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking some stackoverflow's about getActionView() null problem,
The 2nd answer at [getActionView() of my MenuItem return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286768/getactionview-of-my-menuitem-return-null) fixed my problem.
I had to use namespace **app** instaed of **android**.

Really painful!

Comment: Oh, are you kidding me? I posted you more simple, and 100% work solution without unnecessary code and you... oh, whatever... You know what? just, forget about it...

Answer (score 1):

**Search menu item**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/searchPlace"
    android:title="@string/search_hint"
    android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>
```

**Activity code**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.searchPlace).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
    return true;
}

private OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new OnQueryTextListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        //if you need this
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
        //your code
        return true;
    }
};
```

In this this case you dont need searchable configuration, dont need strokes in manifest, dont need SearchManager and other stuff. Just declare search item in the menu and thats it.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I'm not sure, and I don't know how to check it - but I am pretty sure my getActionVIew() returns NULL.