# Check textview and get it return as a null

Tags: java, android, android-studio, menu, textview

I am working on my java snippet that I want to check if the TextView in the menu is exist or not. If the textview is not exist then I want to return it as a null so I could do something.

When I try this:

```
if (total_inbox_unread > 0) {
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType") TextView total_inbox_tv = (TextView) 
    menu.getItem(0).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.total_mailbox);
}

if (total_inbox_tv == null) {
    ...do something
}
```

I am getting this:

Process: com.loginpage, PID: 29159
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Here is the full code:

```
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
    _fragment.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    Menu menu = (Menu) navigationView.getMenu();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService
         (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_items, null);


    if (total_inbox_unread > 0) {
          @SuppressLint("ResourceType") TextView total_inbox_tv = (TextView) menu.getItem(0).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.total_mailbox);
          //LinearLayout mailbox_layout = (LinearLayout) menu.getItem(0).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.mailbox_layout);

          if (total_inbox_tv == null) {
              //LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_items, null);
              //TextView total_mailbox_tv = (TextView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.total_mailbox);
              total_inbox_tv = linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.total_mailbox);
              int total_mailbox = total_inbox_unread;
              total_inbox_tv.setText(Integer.toString(total_mailbox));
              total_inbox_tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.black));
              menu.getItem(0).setActionView(linearLayout);
          }
          else
          {
              int total_inbox = Integer.parseInt(total_inbox_tv.getText().toString());

              if (total_inbox_unread > total_inbox) {
                  total_inbox_tv.setText(Integer.toString(total_inbox_unread));
              }
              else if (total_inbox_unread < total_inbox) {
                  total_inbox_tv.setText(Integer.toString(total_inbox_unread));
              }
          }
      }
      else if (total_inbox_unread == 0) {
           if (!(menu.getItem(0).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.total_mailbox) == null)) {
                 LinearLayout inbox_layout = (LinearLayout) menu.getItem(0).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.mailbox_layout);
                 TextView total_inbox_tv = (TextView) menu.getItem(0).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.total_mailbox);
                 int total_inbox = Integer.parseInt(total_inbox_tv.getText().toString());

                 if (total_inbox >= 1) {
                    inbox_layout.removeAllViews();
                    inbox_layout.invalidate();
                 }
             }
         }
```

There is no textview in the subgroup under the menu. I can only add the submenu

How I can get the textview to return as a null when I have no textview in the menu??

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace of the exception

Comment: Null is returned in `getActionView()` call, so calling `Null.findViewById(R.id.total_mailbox)` throws  null pointer exception.

Comment: Suggest take a look to this to see whether it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286768/getactionview-of-my-menuitem-return-null